# customizable product (with options shown) in related product section

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Using magneto, on the product page of "product A" is it possible to have "product B" and "product C" - which are set as configurable products - in the related products section and allow choosing their respective options - all from the product page of "product A"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Is it as simple as that, or can you provide more detail/commentary?

Comment: It highly depends on desired functionality. I can project, that an experienced Magento developer can build it in about a week. There is no simple 10-lines-of-code solution for that.